# Logical OR error in Linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have written a shell script for printing book:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    exit 1
fi
filename=$1
options=""
mode="color"
first=""
last=""
pages="All pages from"
shift
until [ -z "$1" ]
do
    if [ $1 = "gray" -o $1 = "grey" -o $1 = "grayscale" -o $1 = "greyscale" ]
    then
        options=" -o ColorModel=KGray"
        mode=$1
    elif [ $1 = "from" ]
    then
        shift
        first="$1"
    elif [ $1 = "to" ]
    then
        shift
        last="$1"
    fi
    shift
done
if [ $first -o $last ]
then
    pages="Pages"
    if [ $first ]
    then
        pages="$pages $first"
        first=" -f $first"
    else
        pages="$pages 1"
    fi
    if [ $last ]
    then
        pages="$pages to $last"
        last=" -l $last"
    else
        pages="$pages to last"
    fi
    pages="$pages from"
fi
echo -n "$pages $filename will be printed in $mode mode. If it's OK, put paper in your printer and press ENTER. Else press CTRL+C. "
read ack
pdftops$first$last -expand $filename - | psbook | psnup -2 > tmp.ps
psselect -o tmp.ps | lpr$options
echo -n "Wait for the end of printing, then take printed pages, put them back in printer to print on other side and press ENTER again."
read ack
psselect -e -r tmp.ps | lpr$options
rm tmp.ps
exit 0
```

When I saved this code to file "print-book" and ran it like:

```
print-book test.pdf gray
```

I got this:

```
Pages 1 to last from test.pdf will be printed in gray mode. If it's OK, put paper in your printer and press ENTER. Else press CTRL+C
```

i.e. condition "$first -o $last" was true. But if check "$first" and "$last" separately in this place, they both are false.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$first` and `$last` are empty, `[ $first -o $last ]` will be evaluated as `[ -o ]`, which is not what you want.

You should instead use `[ "$first" -o "$last" ]`, which is equivalent to `[ "" -o "" ]`.

---

Never use variables without quoting them (unless you know what you're doing): the results will be unexpected most of the times.

Also, test weird behaviors interactively in the command line: just input `[ $a -o $b ] && echo y` to quickly see what's going on and being able to play with your variables.

Comment: The POSIX standard recommends against use `-o` for this very reason, and suggests using `[ ... ] || [ ... ]` in place of `[ ... -o ... ]`.